# Sorting PDF reports into proper directories "TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not list"

Tags: python, sorting, rename

I am currently getting an error:

```
line 24, in <module> pdfFileobj = open(pdfFiles, 'rb') TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not list"
```

Trying to automate part of my job.

At my job I am constantly creating new PDF reports for clients.

My goal is to sort all of the PDF reports from my download directory parse the reports for 3 pieces of data first name last name and report type then I need to compare the data to the appointments on my shared outlook calendar to get the date of the client's appointment. then I need to move the reports to our clients directory on the shared drive and create a client specific sub-directory if it does not exist lastly I need to rename the reports in this format **LastnameDD-MM-YY Firstname Report type**

```
import os
import winreg
import PyPDF2 as p2
import glob

def get_download_path():
    """Returns the default downloads path for linux or windows"""
    if os.name == 'nt':
        sub_key = r'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders'
        downloads_guid = '{374DE290-123F-4565-9164-39C4925E467B}'
        with winreg.OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER, sub_key) as key:
            location = winreg.QueryValueEx(key, downloads_guid)[0]
        return location
    else:
        return os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), 'downloads')

os.chdir(get_download_path())

pdfFiles = [glob.glob("*.pdf")]
pdfs = []


while pdfFiles:
        pdfFileobj = open(pdfFiles, 'rb')
        pdfReader = p2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileobj)
        pdfFiles.pop(-1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- First of all, `glob.glob(str)` returns a list, and so, you adding the extra square brackets are unnecessary.
- Second, `open()` takes in a str, bytes or os.PathLike object as an argument, not a list.

**Change this part:**

```
while pdfFiles:
        pdfFileobj = open(pdfFiles, 'rb')
        pdfReader = p2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileobj)
        pdfFiles.pop(-1)
```

**to:**

```
for file in pdfFiles:
        pdfFileobj = open(file, 'rb')
        pdfReader = p2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileobj)
```

*(also note that `pop()` by default removes the `-1` index, so you don't have to pass in the argument)*

---

All together:

```
import os
import winreg
import PyPDF2 as p2
import glob

def get_download_path():
    """Returns the default downloads path for linux or windows"""
    if os.name == 'nt':
        sub_key = r'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders'
        downloads_guid = '{374DE290-123F-4565-9164-39C4925E467B}'
        with winreg.OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER, sub_key) as key:
            location = winreg.QueryValueEx(key, downloads_guid)[0]
        return location
    else:
        return os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), 'downloads')

os.chdir(get_download_path())

pdfFiles = glob.glob("*.pdf")
pdfs = []

for file in pdfFiles:
        pdfFileobj = open(file, 'rb')
        pdfReader = p2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileobj)
```

---

____________________________ UPDATED FOR LOOPING: ____________________________

```
import os
import winreg
import PyPDF2 as p2
import glob
from time import sleep

def get_download_path():
    """Returns the default downloads path for linux or windows"""
    if os.name == 'nt':
        sub_key = r'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders'
        downloads_guid = '{374DE290-123F-4565-9164-39C4925E467B}'
        with winreg.OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER, sub_key) as key:
            location = winreg.QueryValueEx(key, downloads_guid)[0]
        return location
    else:
        return os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), 'downloads')

os.chdir(get_download_path())

while True:
    pdfFiles = glob.glob("*.pdf")
    pdfs = []

    for file in pdfFiles:
            pdfFileobj = open(file, 'rb')
            pdfReader = p2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileobj)
    sleep(300) # stop the program for 300 seconds
```

Comment: What should I do if I want to iterate this code many times since I cannot use a while loop in this scenario?

Comment: Why would you want to iterate through the code multiple times?

Comment: I want to iterate multiple times because the pdfFiles list is being updated 20-50 times a day.

Comment: Well, you *can* use a `while` loop... Would you like me to add that to the post?

Comment: oh really? that would be great!

Comment: @JasonHanner Done.

Comment: Glad I can help!